# Updating WordPress or plugins causes site issues (due to API, I think)

Tags: updates, cache, apc

I have a problem with all of the sites I host on my server.  Whenever someone updates WordPress of plugins, I manually have to restart Apache to get things to work properly.

Should the update process clear the APC caches itself, if if so, any ideas what could cause this to not work correctly?

I've checked the latest victim site, & there's not caching plugin on this site, for reference,

Comment: What exactly not going right after updates? You describe what you do, but not what restart fixes. You'll probably have to enable [`WP_DEBUG` mode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Debugging_in_WordPress), and since it's production — disable error display and log them. It's too hard to guess what might be going wrong.

Comment: Sorry @Rarst … I don't get any errors, per-say, but the 'upgrade available' message is still displayed, and sometimes the admin pages stylesheet doesn't load